# Removing a scipt from /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ properly

Tags: systemd, suspend

So I had manually created a script called `soundconfigreboot` which contained the following lines

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    post)
        systemctl --user restart pipewire.service pipewire-pulse.socket
        ;;
esac
```

in the directory
`/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`
Following this, I decided that I no longer wanted the said script running, so I removed the file using elevated permissions `sudo rm soundconfigreboot`

Since then, just to make sure whether the changes were applied or not, I tried rebooting, followed by putting the system to sleep and then turning it back on again and the script still runs for some reason. I can see the sinks / sources (pactl) giving visual feedback (pop-ups) everytime I enter the login screen after coming back from sleep.

I am 100% sure that the script still runs post suspend and my source/sink selections get messed up - which is another direct indicator of the script running post suspend

Really confused here.

Comment: A better place for it would have been under /etc/systemd; did a copy of it get put there by chance?

Comment: You removed a script starting the service. Might the `pipewire.service` still be running nevertheless? What is the output of `systemctl status pipewire pipewire.socket`? If so disable the service.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no that area seems to be clean

Comment: @FelixJN the output returns that no such units have been found, but i do find it under the list of units running when i pass `systemctl status` at the very end of all units

Comment: Sorry my comment missed the `--user` - did you take that into account for checking the status?